# HP Mini 110 netbook

Tags: windows-7, windows

RE: HP Mini 110 Notebook will not boot up. Info on screen “the boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible” Status: Oxc000000f

Comment: basically you need to recover your boot disk using your Windows CD. How to do that is located here. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

Comment: Pleas don't ask two questions at a time. Recovering your license key is a separate issue and requires a separate question.

Comment: @AlanTuring - Your deleted answer seems correct. Why did you delete it?

Comment: I didn't know how to format it ^_^

Comment: @AlanTuring - just un-delete it an leave it as is.

Comment: there i formatted it :p

Answer (score 1):

So basically you need to recover your bootrec using a Windows disc. The entire documentation is listed [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392).

**To run the Bootrec.exe tool, you must start Windows RE. To do this, follow these steps:**

1. Put the Windows Vista or Windows 7 installation disc in the disc drive, and then start the       computer.
2. Press a key when you are prompted. Select a language, a time, a
   currency, a keyboard or an input method, and then click Next.
3. Click Repair your computer. Click the operating system that you want to
   repair, and then click Next.
4. In the System Recovery Options dialog
   box, click Command Prompt. Type Bootrec.exe, and then press ENTER.

**Note To start the computer from the Windows Vista or Windows 7 DVD, the computer must be configured to start from the DVD drive. For more information about how to configure the computer to start from the DVD drive, see the documentation that is included with the computer or contact the computer manufacturer.**